# Call a function located in another file in Jira Script editor to accesss some constant values

Tags: jira, atlassian-sourcetree, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin

I am implementing a fragment with a REST endpoint and I am writing the condition as a script. I need to call a function from another class called Configuration_CreateMultipleSubtasks.groovy.

Here is the structure of my files in the script editor

[image]
I need to call a function located in the file Configuration_CreateMultipleSubtasks.groovy. The latter file contains some constant values that I decided to store there.

Here is the code for my condition Fragment_Condition_CreateMultipleSubtasks.groovy. I would like to call the function getSubTaskCreatorHashMap() which is located in another file given that this function stores some constant values.

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor

import com.atlassian.jira.security.plugin.ProjectPermissionKey

import com.atlassian.jira.plugin.webfragment.model.JiraHelper

import CreateMultipleSubtasks.Configuration_CreateMultipleSubtasks

import com.atlassian.jira.project.Project

import org.apache.log4j.Logger

def log = Logger.getLogger("atlassian-jira.log")

Configuration_CreateMultipleSubtasks conf= new Configuration_CreateMultipleSubtasks(); 

 def subTaskCreatorHashMap= conf.getSubTaskCreatorHashMap()

String projectKey1 = subTaskCreatorHashMap["projectKey"] ;

String issueTypeName1 =subTaskCreatorHashMap["issueTypeName"];

String projectKey = "PIE" ;

String issueTypeName ="Defect";

def val=jiraHelper.project?.key==projectKey  &&  issue.issueType.name==issueTypeName

log.warn("MOUNA CONDITION IS TRUE"+ projectKey1+" "+issueTypeName1)

return val
```

Obviously, my import is not working since I am not able to print projectKey1 and projejctKey2 in the code below.

```
 public  class Configuration_CreateMultipleSubtasks {

 

    static def getSubTaskCreatorHashMap(){

        def map = [itracCreatemultiplesubtasksIssueTypesId:5, 

        itracCreatemultiplesubtasksProjectCategoriesID: [10011, 10200, 10220, 10230, 10240, 10670, 10170, 11170, 11270, 11870, 11871, 11872, 11873, 11874, 11875, 12470], 

        itracCreatemultiplesubtasksProjectCategoriesURL: "http://itrac-sustservice.eur.ad.sag:5555/web/subtaskmgr/Login.jsp?iTrac=:1:&reporter=:2:", 

        projectKey: "PIE", 

        issueTypeName: "Defect"]

        return map

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer, the solution is to write a package declaration before the imports that fixed the problem